# JAVA - File I/O cant get file to read

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, java-io

I'm trying to get `inventory.csv` to load in Eclipse, and I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put the location of the file (Example: `c:\\Users\\...`) or if I even need it, considering it's in the same folder. I recieved an "unable to load inventory.csv." output. My driver finishes the rest of the program with no errors afterwards.

```
public int readInventory(Automobile[] inventory)
{
    final String FILENAME = "inventory.csv";
    int size = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner("inventory.csv");
    try
    {
        input = new Scanner(new File(FILENAME));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file " + FILENAME + ".");
    }
    // ...
    return size;
}
```

Here is the output I'm getting with no syntax errors.

```
Unable to open file inventory.csv.
```

Comment: Try to print the value of `new File(FILENAME).getAbsolutePath()`  to see the expected location of your file .

Comment: When you get an exception, *print the exception*. Not some futile message of your own devising. There is very little information in that. There is lots more in the exception itself.

Comment: And it is expected that all syntax errors to have been corrected well before you post anything here. They aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: And changing `Scanner input = null;` to something else doesn't fix any syntax errors, as it isn't a syntax error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> considering it's in the same folder.

Same folder as what? `inventory.csv` was not present in the current working directory when you executed your program.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are trying to read a CSV file from a single Java program then directly keep your file in the same location where the class was created.
2. In eclipse, keep the CSV file directly under your project directory. As you can see, the Employee.xml file directly under JavaPrac project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2xJJ.jpg)

Comment: I have it in the same location and I'm calling it in only a single project, but among 4 other classes, but how would I go about calling it in a class under the same project?

Comment: 'Where the class was created' has exactly nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this

```
        try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr)
       String lime=br.readLine();
       br.close();
       catch(Exeption e){}
```

Comment: *Why* exactly should he try this exception-ignoring, input-ignoring, identical-in-its-effects, misspelt-variable-containing code, as opposed to what the OP has already posted?